# Ubuntu-Server 20.04.3 installer immediately crashes

Tags: boot, system-installation, crash

TL;DR: Ubuntu-Server immediately crashes after installer loads, I'm in desperate need for some help, details below

So I need an Ubuntu-Server rather urgently and was given some random hardware that was lying around. It's a Dell Power Edge 230 with only 8GB of RAM, and a 3Ghz Quad core. I haven't yet figured out what the RAID config is or what drives are installed (if you have any pointers on what information to look for and how, feel free to share).

Here is what I've done so far: Used this tutorial to make a bootable Flash-Drive, than plugged it into the rear USB port of my Server, pressed F11 to load boot Manager, selected One-Shot BIOS Boot menu, selected USB-Drive;

Now onto the the Problem, when I select the drive it goes on to boot Ubuntu, starting with this whole screen in the dark purple-ish ubuntu color and a logo of a keyboard, an arrow and a person (wich I've never seen before), then it loads the regular stuff (cloud init etc) and then gives me the select language screen, after a few seconds (no matter if I interact or not) it displays a message saying that an unknown error occurred

Ive tried with different USB-Drives same result

If you need some more info, let me know

I would really appreciate some advice, or what you have done if you've had this problem

TL;DR: Ubuntu-Server immediately crashes after installer loads, I'm in desperate need for some help

Comment: Did you verify the ISO after download?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then ensure the media validation occurred successfully?   (*I'm a desktop user so have minimal experience with live server installs, but in my QA-tests the procedure are the same; and I'm doing it currently with the canary installer which works almost the same as `subiquity` on Ubuntu Server; you didn't mention any checks as to what went wrong; did you explore for errors? - squashfs are bad ISO or bad write to installation media*)

Comment: @guiverc I just ran the validation, checks out.  I didn't quite understand what you meant here. "you didn't mention any checks as to what went wrong; did you explore for errors? - squashfs are bad ISO or bad write to installation media" can you elaborate furter

Comment: Can you boot the computer in any way? Preinstalled operating system, Ubuntu desktop live usb, etc? Ps your question is a bit misleading; the server isn't crashing - you have never run the server - it's the installer that is crashing.

Comment: You will need to determine what the RAID level is. Ubuntu does not support RAID5 for a number of reasons, and that can be the reason for the failure. If you can boot into the RAID configuration menu, then you should be able to confirm this.

Comment: I switch to terminal & scan the `journalctl` for the md5check scan complete messages which validate there were no issues with the installation media (*sorry I forget exactly what I type; but I find it quite easily*)..  That's what I rule out first, as any *squashfs* discovered just mean other results cannot really be trusted. Then I scan looking for other *generic* (ie. non-install) issues before getting to the installer which sounds like `subiquity` to me (*your question wasn't clear*) but I'm a desktop user & QA-tester so have *far* less experience with that installer sorry.

Comment: random hardware that was lying around upps how long lying around?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the release image (downloaded directly from the Ubuntu website), try using the daily CD image.

You can find daily images at [http://cdimage.ubuntu.com](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/).

The current Ubuntu Server daily image for the legacy installer is [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/).
the current Ubuntu Server daily image for thew new installer is [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/focal/daily-live/current/).

Also be sure to check the checksum of any downloaded image, to make sure the image wasn't corrupted during download.